# Relationshiop between central bank official currency rates and spot forex

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, market-data, fx, currency

Central banks publish official figures for domestic interest rates, as well as spot currency rates for a few select countries (largest trading partners).

To prevent arbitrage, I "expect" that in the absence of any intraday shocks to the system, the central banks figures will (and the possibility of arbitrage), should keep intraday prices "in check" - that is within reason.

I do not trade forex actively myself, so I do not know if this inference from the fundamentals (pun unintended), is borne out in practise.

My question therefore is this:

**In lieu of actual EOD data for forex market data, is it practical (i.e. sensible), to use bank official rates as a proxy for actual EOD spot currency rates?**

This would obviously be flawed for intraday trading, but for lower frequency trading, I imagine that the series (official rates and market spot values), will be highly cointegrated - and therefore, the former can act as a proxy for the latter - am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use e.g. the ECB daily official foreign exchange rate data as a reliable and consistent daily timeseries.  ECB does a fixing at 14:15 CET, by some methodology they call a "daily concertation procedure".  I don't easily find a description of the details (are they considering only traded prices, or bids and offers?  How long of a time window around 14:15 may used?  etc.)  But for purposes of daily vol, correlation, etc. such details won't matter.  It is a consistent dataset with a consistent methodology giving daily market exchange rates.

Comment: Do beware of mixing data from different sources though!  Different fixing times mixed on the same daily timeline means that some are "in the future" relative to others.